# linux + compare between two folders

Tags: linux, shell-script, java, diff

under **/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-get** folder and **/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-put** 
we have jar files

```
/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-get/stax-api-1.0.1.jar
/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-get/stringtemplate-3.2.1.jar
/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-get/tephra-api-0.7.0.jar
/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-get/tephra-core-0.7.0.jar
/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-get/xmlenc-0.52.jar
/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-get/tephra-hbase-compat-1.1-0.7.0.jar
/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-get/tools-1.7.0.jar
/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-get/zkclient-0.9.jar
/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-get/twill-api-0.6.0-incubating.jar
/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-get/zookeeper-3.4.9.jar


/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-put/stax-api-1.0.1.jar
/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-put/stringtemplate-3.2.1.jar
/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-put/tephra-api-0.7.0.jar
/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-put/tephra-core-0.7.0.jar
/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-put/xmlenc-0.52.jar
/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-put/tephra-hbase-compat-1.1-0.7.0.jar
/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-put/tools-1.7.0.jar
/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-put/zkclient-0.9.jar
/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-put/twill-api-0.6.0-incubating.jar
/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-put/zookeeper-3.4.9.jar
```

what is the best approach to compare between folders?

the target is to find if chksum/md5 of all jars is equal to the other folder

note - in some case new jar files can be added to one of the folders so quantity of jar files can be diff between folders

meanwhile we are using

```
diff --brief --recursive /usr/lib/ambari-metrics-put /usr/lib/ambari-metrics-get
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- cd to `/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-get/`
- `md5sum *.jar >/tmp/jars.md5`
- cd to `/usr/lib/ambari-metrics-put/`
- `md5sum -c /tmp/jars.md5`

Typically, use the folder with the most files as the first one (the one where you generate the MD5 list).

Comment: I mentioned my approach - diff --brief --recursive /usr/lib/ambari-metrics-put /usr/lib/ambari-metrics-get  , why your suggestion is better from my ?